# Optimizing SQL for repeating calculations

Tags: sql

```
select *, (T3.price_usd - T1.price_usd)/T3.price_usd as b
from ticker T1
INNER JOIN mycoins T2
   ON T1.symbol = T2.symbol
INNER JOIN ticker T3
  ON T1.symbol = T3.symbol
WHERE T1.timer = (Select max(timer) from ticker)  
  AND T3.timer = (Select min(timer) from ticker where timer 
                      > (Select max(timer) from ticker - 60*60*24*7*2))
```

The above code has the issue that `(Select max(timer) from ticker)` is executed multiple times in the query. This is because the maximum timer value is used several times. Is there a way to improve this code so we can determine max timer once and then re-use that value?

Comment: tag the DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, etc...) which u r using `SQL` is just Query Language.

Comment: Is your query running without any error?

Comment: That is better solved using window functions

Answer (score 2):

*Optimize query for your scenario is with following approach ,SQL Server !!*

```
-- Declare Varaibles 
declare @MaxTime int
declare @MinTime int

-- Set values ,Need not to use inside query as recurrncy reduce processing
Select @MaxTime=max(timer) from ticker
Select @MinTime=min(timer) from ticker where timer > (Select max(timer) from ticker - 60*60*24*7*2))


-- Create complex query 
select *, (T3.price_usd - T1.price_usd)/T3.price_usd as b
from ticker T1
INNER JOIN mycoins T2
ON T1.symbol = T2.symbol
INNER JOIN ticker T3
ON T1.symbol = T3.symbol
WHERE T1.timer = @MaxTime  AND
T3.timer = @MinTime
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeh great ,You can accept the solution .If it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use store procedure, using it is quite easily adjust and good for performance.

Here is sample for MS SQL Server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @max int

    Set @max = (Select max(timer) from ticker);

    select *, (T3.price_usd - T1.price_usd)/T3.price_usd as b
        from ticker T1
        INNER JOIN mycoins T2
        ON T1.symbol = T2.symbol
        INNER JOIN ticker T3
        ON T1.symbol = T3.symbol
        WHERE T1.timer = @max  AND
        T3.timer = (Select min(timer) from ticker where timer > (@max - 60*60*24*7*2))

END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
declare @MaxTime bigint
declare @MinTime bigint

Select @MaxTime = max(timer) from ticker
Select @MinTime = min(timer) from ticker where timer > (@MaxTime - 60*60*24*7*2)

select *, (T3.price_usd - T1.price_usd)/T3.price_usd as b
from ticker T1
INNER JOIN mycoins T2
   ON T1.symbol = T2.symbol
INNER JOIN ticker T3
  ON T1.symbol = T3.symbol
WHERE T1.timer = @MaxTime  
  AND T3.timer = @MinTime
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.